# TCP Reset Attack

Tags: tcp, reset

I'am trying to implement a PoC for the TCP Reset attack. I am using 3 VMs(host A, host B and the attacker). Host A connects through SSH to host B. The attacker sniffs the connection between the 2 hosts and it sends a RST packet to Host A(I am pretty sure that A receives that packet because I captured the traffic with Wireshark). The problem is that even if that RST packet if received by Host A, the connection between the 2 hosts is not closed and I don't understand why. I think that the problem might be related to the seq number and the ACK value I configure in the RST packet, because I use random numbers which are grater than all the seq numbers and ACK values I noticed in the Wireshark capture.

Comment: Never done this, but I'm pretty sure a TCP Reset attack is between two devices; the client (attacker) and the host.  To my knowledge, the client opens a connection and continuously sends RST packets to keep resetting the session, using bandwidth from the host in the progress.

Comment: I found the answer here : http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Book/book_sample_tcp.pdf